# Is it possible to parse only "version":"8.9" from json file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, json

I have this json data and I want to parse only version:8.9 from it is it possible to do ?

```
{
      "version": "8.9",
      "description": "Long-Term Support version - Hardening for long-term reliability, bug fixes and small improvements",
      "releaseDate": "2021-05-04",
      "changeLogUrl": "https://jira.sonarsource.com/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10930&version=16710",
      "downloadUrl": "https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonarqube/sonarqube-8.9.0.43852.zip",
      "plugins": {
        "requireUpdate": [
          {
            "key": "codehawk",
            "name": "Codehawk Java",
            "category": "External Analysers",
            "description": "Analyze Java code smell",
            "homepageUrl": "https://github.com/SDPMLab/CodeHawk",
            "editionBundled": false,
            "version": "1.5"
          },
```

Answer (score 2):

Provided, the `json` is properly closed, like

```
{
      "version": "8.9",
      "description": "Long-Term Support version - Hardening for long-term reliability, bug fixes and small improvements",
      "releaseDate": "2021-05-04",
      "changeLogUrl": "https://jira.sonarsource.com/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10930&version=16710",
      "downloadUrl": "https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonarqube/sonarqube-8.9.0.43852.zip",
      "plugins": {
        "requireUpdate": [
          {
            "key": "codehawk",
            "name": "Codehawk Java",
            "category": "External Analysers",
            "description": "Analyze Java code smell",
            "homepageUrl": "https://github.com/SDPMLab/CodeHawk",
            "editionBundled": false,
            "version": "1.5"
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

... you can use `jq`:

```
jq -r '.version' data.json
```

---

You may need to install `jq`:

```
sudo apt install jq
```